# Chrome Removing "extenstions_to_open" from master_preferences file

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

I am currently trying to configure Google Chrome on a bunch of Clients to open Citrix Receiver ICA files automatically.

To enable the automatic launch of ICA files, I added the "extensions_to_open" option to my master_preferences file, which is used as a template for new profiles. This file is added before Chrome is about to be launched for the first time so there's no chance of a profile being created before the master_preferences file is configured correctly.

The Issue I am experiencing is the following:

My file looks like this:

```
{
    "distribution": {
        "msi": true,
        "system_level": true,
        "verbose_logging": true,
        "allow_downgrade": false,
    },
    "download": {
        "directory_upgrade": true,
        "extensions_to_open": "ica"
    }
}
```

After I launch Chrome for the first time, however, the file looks like this:

```
{
    "distribution": {
        "msi": true,
        "system_level": true,
        "verbose_logging": true,
        "allow_downgrade": false,
    },
    "download": {
        "directory_upgrade": true,
    }
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing? Why is Chrome just straight up removing the extensions_to_open line from my file?

Information on Chrome's options seems to be sparse but the extensions_to_open option is still listed in Chromium's source code: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc#1756

If there's a smarter way of configuring this option, I'd also be grateful to hear about it.